# X-Y coordinates unknown coordinate system?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, coordinate-system, format

I received a .dbf file with coordinates in a numerical format I have not been able to identify (for example (X,Y): 6151578.03, 2090875.69). These coordinates represent bus stop locations in the Orange County area (California) and I need to transform them into Lat-Long format (once I figure out what the original format is).

I am using ArcMap 10.2.2.

Comment: Is there any documentation available at all? US data can be in a whole bunch of units: State Plane, UTM, and even UTM in US Survey feet.

Comment: Not yet, I recently asked the transit agency to share with me their GCS system/protocol, and tried to insert the X-Y data into ArcMAP with different GCS/projections with no results....;

Answer (score 1):

Change system coordinat major frame to WGS84, after then recalculate point XY in decmicial degrees.

[image]

[image]

If you are use geographic coordinate system you can do not change coordinate frame and go to recalculate

If its single task you can use this [transformer](http://cs2cs.mygeodata.eu/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply GRM!...will try the proposed solution...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Orange CountyBus Stop Shapefile has a .prj file that indicates the data is cast in this Coordinate System - NAD_1983_StatePlane_California_VI_FIPS_0406_Feet. Within ArcMap, you can view the Source Tab of the Layer properties to see a data layers Spatial Reference.